# SQL server installation doesnt start

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2014-express

I have downloaded Microsoft SQL server 2014 express and I can't launch the setup. When I start the installer, it shows me an error box with no description.

[image: Screenshot of Setup-Error]

Comment: Good on Microsoft for the helpful feedback :-) ... Did you see anything unusual happening during the installation?  At a first guess, I might just uninstall and reinstall again.

Comment: Did you succeed in reinstalling SQL Server? Did you try executing the Setup as Administrator (supposedly you are installing it on a windows server or client)? By the way: which Windows Version are you running?

Comment: I know it has been a while however I have manged to overcome this  by reinstalling it on a windows 10 machine and it worked. Thanks for your effort guys :)